# Mistake on Wikipedia: Completeness of Filtration and Completeness of Individual Probability Spaces

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, filtrations

A probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ is called complete iff every subset $\tilde{N}$ of a set $N \in \mathcal{A}$ of measure $0$ is measurable, i.e. if $\mathbb{P}(N) = 0$ and $\tilde{N} \subseteq N$ implies that $\tilde{N}\in \mathcal{A}$. In other words, for $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ to be complete, the inclusion
$$ \mathcal{N}:= \{ \tilde{N} \subseteq \Omega \mid \exists N \in \mathcal{A}: \mathbb{P}(N) = 0 \ \land \ \tilde{N} \subseteq N  \} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$$
has to hold.

(A) On Wikipedia, a *filtration* $(\mathcal{A}_t)_{t \in I}$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ is defined to be complete iff, for all $t \in I$, it holds that $\mathcal{N} \subseteq \mathcal{A}_t$.

(B) **Furthermore, it is claimed that definition (A) is equivalent to the statement that $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}_t, \mathbb{P})$ is complete for all $t \in I$.**

I don't think that this equivalence holds and this is a mistake. It is easy to show that (A) implies (B), but I don't see how the converse can be true. Do you agree, or am I missing something?

Kind regards,
Joker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim enunciated in (B) is incorrect, as you have noted. **Example:** Suppose that a standard 1-dimensional Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t\in[0,\infty)}$ is defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\Bbb P)$. For each $t\ge 0$ let $\mathcal A_t$ be the $\Bbb P$-completion of $\sigma\{B_s:0\le s\le t\}$, and let $\mathcal A$ be the $\Bbb P$-completion of $\sigma\{B_s:s\ge 0\}$. The event $C:=\{\omega\in\Omega: \lim_{r\to\infty,r\in\Bbb Q}{B_r(\omega)\over r}$ fails to exist$\}$ is an element of $\mathcal A$ with $\Bbb P(C)=0$;  but $C\notin\mathcal A_t$, for each $t>0$. In this case, (B) holds but (A) does not.

Comment: Thank you! How do you conclude though that $\mathbb{P}(C) = 0$ and that $C \notin \mathcal{A}_t$ ?

Comment: $\Bbb P(C)=0$ is just the strong law of large numbers for Brownian motion. As $C$ depends on the large-time asymptotic behavior of $(B_t)$, membership in $C$ cannot be determined by an initial segment $(B_s(\omega))_{0\le s\le t}$ of the Brownian path.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks again.